# Rank for each department based upon Salary

Tags: mysql, rank, dense-rank

I have the following table format with 100 values which consists 10 different departments,

```
Dept  name  salary
1     e1    100
1     e2    120
1     e3    140
1     e4    150
```

I want to return rank for each department by their salary(max to min) in each department.if the salary is same the rank should be also same.

```
SELECT    Dept,
          name,
          salary,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Order_emp
FROM      emp p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY Dept, salary DESC;
```

The above query continuously returns the rank.But I need Rank for each dept.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach without using user defined variables and by using correlated sub query

```
select a.*,
(select count(distinct salary)
from emp 
where Dept = a.Dept
and a.salary <= salary
) rank
from emp a
order by Dept,rank
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VDKT57622)

### Explanation

In above query all table data will be fetched along with a rank for each row by using correlated sub query, In sub query count of distinct salary records will be returned from same table but where dept is same (for parent query and sub query table) and salary of outer table is less or equal to the salary of table in sub query so considering following data set

```
Dept  name  salary
1     e1    100
1     e2    120
1     e3    150
1     e4    150
```

There are 2 employees who share same salary = 150 so back to our condition for last row from parent table

```
1     e4    150
```

sub query will calculate  a.150 <= salary from emp and dept is same so there are 2 rows (150,150) in table by doing count distinct salary it will return it as 1, Same case applies on second last row.

Let consider again following row for parent table

```
1     e2    120
```

sub query will calculate  a.120 <= salary from emp and dept is same so there are 3 rows in table (120,150,150) by doing count distinct salary it will return it as a 2

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you please explain the query,what does Select *,(select means??

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran I have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran I advice you to go through the docs first this would be good for you to have clear understanding for [correlated sub queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html)  and [sub queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same using user defined variable to you need use nested `case` statements to check for same dept and for same salary within same department

```
SELECT p.Dept,
       p.name,
       p.salary,
       @curRank := CASE WHEN @dept = p.Dept 
       THEN 
            CASE WHEN @salary = p.salary  
            THEN @curRank 
            ELSE @curRank + 1 
            END
       ELSE @curRank:= 1 END AS Order_emp,
       @dept:= p.Dept,
       @salary := p.salary
FROM(SELECT *
     FROM emp,
     (SELECT @dept:= NULL, @salary:= 0, @curRank := 1) r
     ORDER BY Dept, salary DESC
) p
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/MQZZ73691)

Comment: An Explanation for this too if you dont mind.THEN curRank 
            ELSE curRank + 1 what this two lines do and what FROM(SELECT *
     FROM emp,
     (SELECT dept:= NULL, salary:= 0, curRank := 1) r
     ORDER BY Dept, salary DESC this statement does?